# How can I dynamically add elements to a dropdownlist with Razor/MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dropdown, html-select

I need to change the following dropdownlist in my asp.net application, now I have to add values depending in the type of user, which wasn't required before. The following code works fine, but clearly I'm hardcoding the input of the elements.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Vote, 
    new SelectList(
        new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Selected=true, Text = "Randy", Value = "1" }, 
            new SelectListItem { Selected=false, Text = "Richard", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem { Selected=false, Text = "Bubbles", Value = "3" }, 
            new SelectListItem { Selected=false, Text = "Julian", Value = "4" } 
        }, 
        "Value", 
        "Text"
    ), 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

I'm receiving the list from the controller, and I can loop through it, but I'm not able to use this information as `SelectListItem`s.
Obvioulsy, the first, and the last `SelectListItem`s are special, the first one, has the property `Selected` set to `true`, while the others are set to `false`, that way the first one is selected by default. 
The last one, on the other hand, doesn't have a comma before it's closing tag `}` which the previous ones do, so this is how I'm looping.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < candidatos.Count(); i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        <h4>"First candidate:" + candidatos.ElementAt(i)</h4>
    }
    else if (i < candidatos.Count() - 1)
    {
        <h4>"Not first nor last:" + candidatos.ElementAt(i)</h4>
    }
    else
    {
        <h4>"Last candidate:" + candidatos.ElementAt(i)</h4>
    }
}
```

So this is output correctly, but I really need help with the syntax, I have been trying hard to combine this iteration with the syntax that I hardcoded and properly shows elements as items in a dropdownlist, but I can't figure out how to, yet.

This is how I tried to combine both stuff, but I'm getting errors.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Voto, new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> { 
    for (var i = 0; i < candidatos.Count(); i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = candidatos.ElementAt(i + 1), Value = (i + 2).ToString() },
    }
    else if (i < candidatos.Count() - 1)
    {
        { new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = candidatos.ElementAt(i + 1), Value = (i + 2).ToString() },
    }
    else
    {
        { new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = candidatos.ElementAt(i + 1), Value = (i + 2).ToString() } }, "Value", "Text" ),
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    }
}
```

browser yells at me saying the expression needs a closing `}` after

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Voto, new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> {
```

I think it doesn't realize I'm providing the corresponding closing tags, and missing elements using the for loop, but obviously, because I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You can't add for statements in list initializers.

Comment: so @claudiom248, do you have any idea on how I can do what I'm trying?

Comment: Yes, give me just 5 minutes.

Comment: you may need to create a variable for your `SelectListItem` and store there whatever in your `for` loop. Then reference that variable to your `DropDownListFor`
`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Voto, [yourSelectListItemVariableHere])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is create a new variable that will store our SelectListItem. Then we will iterate on our "candidatos" and we will add a new item with properties that will be set taking into consideration your logic.

```cs
@{ 
    var selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < candidatos.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = candidatos.ElementAt(i + 1), Value = (i + 2).ToString() });
        }
        else if (i < candidatos.Count() - 1)
        {
             selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = candidatos.ElementAt(i + 1), Value = (i + 2).ToString() });
        }
        else
        {
             selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = candidatos.ElementAt(i + 1), Value = (i + 2).ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, you will pass the new generated list as second parameter to the DropDownListFor method of the Html class.

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Voto, selectListItems, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" });
```

I hope my solution will suit your needs. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Works great, thanks! I would like to know as well what are your thoughts about using Enumarator. That's what I just found out when I was investigating about how to do what I was trying to.

Comment: IMHO I think you don't have to use directly an Enumerator to achieve what you have to do. I would just add complexity to the code.

In any case, I am glad to see that my solution has helped you.